# Is there a function to let opengraph reads the page/post meta dynamically?

Tags: function, facebook-opengraph

I had problem seeing social preview for my links on Whatsapp and Telegram. After research, I found that Og tags created by Yoast should be inserted close to the opening `<head>` tag. I tried it, and it is almost working. But I have two problems I hope you help me get fixed:

1- I get only homepage link preview and nothing for other posts or pages.

2- when i share my homepage link for test on whatsapp and telegram, it doesn't output the image. Only description and title.

But when i check my urls on open graph checker, the tool shows complete information including the image! ^_^

What is the solution for this?

I need a code, maybe a function, maybe something else.. idk. I just want to get rid of it. In other words, I want to put og tags right after `<head>` and put this function which I'm looking for and solve the problem. hopefully.

Comment: You might want to add what (if any) frameworks you are using and where you are hosting your site (Firebase Hosting, Wordpress, AWS, etc) as there may be solutions available specific to that host.

Comment: I am using wordpress on a shared hosting service (linux server). No, I emailed them they said this is not a hosting problem.

Comment: I didn't say that the problem is with your host, just that your options on how to solve the problem might change depending on your host. Using Firebase Hosting as an example - you can serve pre-rendered content, or content optimized/updated for social bots, using Cloud Functions.

Comment: I understand. Can you say it a bit simpler? Do you mean there is a solution to this that I can use?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't work with Wordpress, so I can't be of much help. I was just prompting for more information so that someone else might be able to help.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your positive intention though :). I also hope other fellows help with this.